Identifying a quotation from Dulce Maria Loynaz comparing physical pain to a civil war
She compared physical pain to a civil war in which the body, always taken for granted and obedient, suddenly rebels against the mind, seeking compensation for its losses and defending its rights:

It never demanded anything,’ the mind complains wonderingly about the body. ‘Now it comes … shouting its name in the silence of my nights … the simple, angry beggar who used to sleep every night outside my door.’

Does anyone know which poem this comes from, and perhaps where it was printed?

Where did you come across this quotation?

It was included in a letter as a quote (the writer felt it's description of aging was very apt) and it started me reading the collection Absolute Solitude. They found it while reading a history of Havana, and it was quoted but not cited.

This describes one of Loynaz's Poemas sin Nombre, a collection of her poems published in 1953. None of the poems are given titles, but are simply assigned a roman numeral. Poem XXXV begins:

Como una  guerra civil, como una rebelión sordamente contenida, el
dolor ha estallado en alguna parte de mi tiempo sin darme tiempo a
huir, cogida por sorpresa entre su furia.

In my translation, this would read, "Like a civil war, like a mutely contained rebellion, pain has exploded somewhere in my life without giving me time to flee, caught by surprise in its fury." As the OP noted, here the poet is comparing sudden bodily pain with a civil war. The line about the beggar is the final line of the poem:

Para el mendigo cándido y colérico que dormía todas las noches a mi
puerta.

that is, "For the simple and angry beggar who slept every night at my door."
The complete work can be read (in the original Spanish) here.

Do you know if it has been translated into English?

Google books lists one translation, by Harriet De Onís in 1993: https://books.google.co.uk/books/about/Poems_Without_Name.html?id=RJvgAAAACAAJ&source=kp_book_description&redir_esc=y  I have not read it though, so I can't comment on its quality.
